# How would I embed Meteor views in a Cordova project?

Tags: cordova, meteor

We’re interested in starting a Cordova project (iOS/Android) that would have some embedded Meteor views. This would be in contrast to the normal Meteor way of having a Meteor project that is in control of the whole app. For example, we’d like to use native tabbed navigation that would have one tab using native components and another serving a Meteor view.

I’ve explored using Meteor’s supported “Advanced Build Customization” feature (https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration#advanced-build-customization) but it seems like that’s more for making tweaks to the generated Cordova project rather than having an existing Cordova project with embedded Meteor components.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

We ended up using Ionic: http://ionicframework.com/ which allows us the flexibility to mix native and web components without having to start a Javascript app from scratch. Ionic uses AngularJs and adds some nice tools for building mobile UIs.

I liked Meteor's ability to sync with a remote server and cache the results for offline usage but I can do this manually in our app when needed.